# Swift button error on iOS app but not in playground

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn swift to make free educational app for my country.

I know only the basics of programming and swift, but I am trying to understand iOS development.

I think I am having a problem with scope, but not sure what to do.

With `didMoveToView` being (the required) according to books I read, I can't compile and execute the code. So, when I run it in Xcode iOS App Project, my App crashes (even though it works in playground).

---

### The code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    class fooo {
        static var bar = "hello world!"

        @IBAction func hello_button(sender: AnyObject) {
            print(fooo.bar)
        }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

---

### Below is the Crash log (Occurs on button touch):

```
2016-08-26 07:22:00.512 k[2074:37791] -[k.ViewController hello_button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aa2e670
2016-08-26 07:22:00.521 k[2074:37791] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[k.ViewController hello_button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aa2e670'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00200494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f17e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0020a253 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0013f89d ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0013f46e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f2c0b5 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    6   UIKit                               0x009f2e38 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 118
    7   UIKit                               0x009f2db7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    8   UIKit                               0x00b96f3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 79
    9   UIKit                               0x00b972d4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 433
    10  UIKit                               0x00b962c1 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 714
    11  UIKit                               0x00a7352e -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1095
    12  UIKit                               0x00a745cc -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1159
    13  UIKit                               0x00a15be8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 266
    14  UIKit                               0x009ea769 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7795
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00112e5f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00108aeb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00107f08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00107846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0010765b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x04717664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x047174a1 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x009f0eb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
    23  k                                   0x00012581 main + 145
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02935a25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: not `class` it should be `class func`

Comment: Take a look at this, you are probably missing to connect your button on Interface Builder. Here is how it's done: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, the issue is scope (assuming you connected your button properly as others mentioned):

---

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    class fooo {
        var bar = "hello world!"
        func mSayBar() { print(self.bar)}
    }

    var foo = fooo()

    @IBAction func hello_button(sender: AnyObject) {
        foo.mSayBar()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

`viewDidLoad` is it's own local scope--it doesn't extend any further than the end brace " } "
After the first (millisecond?) everything declared in VDL is no longer alive; thus, it is best for initializing or calling, not declaring.

To declare global, just put everything in a new swift file, or put it outside ALL class scopes. Swift makes global scope easy (but be careful)

You said `viewDidLoad` is required, which is true, but only for *setting up the program*. Most of your logic / functions go outside of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: This is very explaining! I definitely did not understand the book and `viewDidLoad`. It is just a regular function :) Thank you. I feel silly now.

Answer (score 2):

`unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aa2e670` means that the button has been linked to an `IBAction` outlet that isn't defined in your code. Go to your ViewController's Storyboard mode, and right click the button in the subview list. Check if there is an outlet for the **Touch Up Inside** event and if it has the same name as the function in your code that you want to call (in your case it's `hello_button`.

Here's a picture if you didn't understand the above paragraph.

[image]